# limit outputs per line

Tags: java, loops, output

I'm writing a code that finds and prints every number between a user specified value so long as the numbers divisible by 5 and 6, but not both. One of the requirements for the code is for there to be only 10 outputs per line, and that's that part I'm having issues with:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class DivisibleBy5And6
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
 { 
   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   final int PER_LINE = 10;

   int value = 0;

   int count = 0;

   int max = 0;

   String end = ";

   do
  { 
     System.out.print ("\nEnter a minimum number: ");
     value = scan.nextInt();

     System.out.print ("Enter a maximum number: ");
     max = scan.nextInt();

     System.out.print ("\n"); 

        while (value <= max)
        {     
           if ((value % 5) < 1 ^ (value % 6) < 1)
              System.out.print (value + " ");

           value++;

           count++;

           if (count % PER_LINE == 0)
              System.out.println();     
        }

     max = 0;

     count = 0;

     System.out.print ("\n");

     System.out.print ("\nContinue? <y/n> ");
     end = scan.next();

  }while (!end.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));


  } 
}
```

I've messed with the example I was given on how to limit the output, and I've seen the 'count' if statement work and I know why it works, but something about the calculations in the 'value' if statement is making the output look nothing like it's supposed to. If anyone has any idea what I've been missing, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Create an array of size 10. Fill it. Print it. Repeat.

Comment: An additional hint: setting a counter to zero should be made as close where and before it is used, not far up front and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the numbers per line must be done together with printing, not with every investigated number.

```
 while (value <= max)
    {     
       if ((value % 5) < 1 ^ (value % 6) < 1){
          System.out.print (value + " ");
          count++;
          if (count % PER_LINE == 0)
              System.out.println();     
       }
       value++;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty obvious in retrospect. It's working now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should only be updating `count` when you actually print something.  Change your `if` statement to something like this:

```
    while (value <= max)
    {     
        if ((value % 5) < 1 ^ (value % 6) < 1){
            System.out.print (value + " ");
            count++;  //update since we printed something
            if (count % PER_LINE == 0)  //check if we have printed 10 items
                System.out.println();    
        }
        value++;
    }
```

Also you should move your `System.out.println()` in the `if` as well so you only go to the next line after printing 10 numbers.